# Batch- Pipe Firewall status

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, pipe, firewall, titlebar

I am not an advanced scriptor but know of the many possibilities. I have a custom batch file, with menu, for performing several tasks from one window (Such as install from domain, enable/disable firewall, etc) but, I need to pipe the status of Windows 7 machine firewalls to the title bar in a similar format as below:

{---------------}  Tech Tools --- FW:000 {---------------}

The title is 'Tech Tools.' Next to it, it would show the firewall status for all profiles in the form of zeros or ones; zero for disabled, ones for enabled.

So far I have found this to give me the most basic information I could find:

```
   NETSH ADVFIREWALL SHOW ALLPROFILE STATE
```

I have been brainstorming on maybe using IF statements and variablees to set relationships between the STATE info and 1/0 and piping it to TITLE.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm totally not sure if I understand the question , but...

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "states="
for /f "eol=- tokens=2" %%a in ('NETSH ADVFIREWALL SHOW ALLPROFILES STATE^|find /i "state"') do (
    if /i "%%a" EQU "ON" (
        set states=!states!1 
    ) else (
        set states=!states!0
    )
)

title {---------------} Tech Tools --- FW:!states! {---------------}

endlocal
```

Comment: Well, if you would have understood it you would have made it talk, 'cause you sampled exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot. 'dibs'